# Dishonest colleague, employment law question

Tags: bullying, law

A while ago I had an experience with a work colleague where I found out she lied about me to others. This was in relation to a work-related event.  When I let her know that I found this out, she replied in a whatsapp message admitting that she lied and didn't care.  This colleague - I'll call her Anne - is friends with the boss so it seems she is untouchable.

My question now is in how to deal with the resulting situation (It is not the only situation, she has made things difficult before, but this is the most recent).  Many on the team and including the boss love drama and see me as someone to target. I haven't worked closely with this colleague, Anne, before. It's been said informally now by the boss that I will be working closely with Anne on an upcoming project which will mean having to communicate regularly (in an atmosphere where the boss has no issue with unprofessional tactics etc and does nothing to discourage this). There is no reason why it has to be Anne in this role - there are several others who could fulfill the role, but obviously the boss is orchestrating this.

In my next meeting with the boss I will give my response that I refuse to work with Anne on this, because Anne has lied about me to others so cannot be trusted - I have emails and messages proving enough of this.

So my question is, do I have a right under employment law to refuse to work with Anne? Especially when, as I mentioned, there is no reason that it has to be her in particular being assigned to the role.

This is a small office by the way, so there is no big structure, no HR dept.

I would complete the project working with any other member of the team so there is no problem really except for this colleague.

I am willing to lose my job, if necessary, rather than have to work closely with this colleague in the role as described.

If I have to lose the job because of this, I would be going for litigation.

Comment: This depends on your location as employment law varies by location.  If you are in the US, then your only options are to do what your boss asks ( nothing illegal is being asked ) or find a new company to work for.

Comment: Need to be a bit more specific than Europe likely; can you put a specific country? Laws vary a lot.

Comment: Did you show the boss the proof you have that Anne lied?

Comment: You need to make sure your boss is actually aware of the lies and their malicious nature regardless of whether you think they will side with Anne. Especially if you want to take the nuclear option and file a lawsuit.

Comment: My boss lies about me multiple times each month and openly admits it. It makes me want to avoid him, but I can't. I can't do anything about it except document, document, document, and look for a new job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I'm completely rewriting this question because of some comments made by the OP (since deleted) indicating that they don't know what it was that "Anne" said, or if the boss believed Anne, but are sure it's serious because of "the atmosphere".

It's going to be absolutely impossible to establish any sort of wrongdoing without knowing what was said. "X said bad things about me but I don't know what they are" is not the sort of complaint that HR can take up, nor a lawyer take action on.

Write down everything you have observed that makes you think there is a hostile atmosphere - everything that everyone said to you, or said in your presence, that you consider hostile. Be very specific, and don't rely on interpretations. At this stage I would recommend talking this over with someone who knows you well but can also be honest with you. If you have colleagues who you get on well with ask them about whether anyone has been spreading rumours about you.

Next, if you are in a union or professional association consult them before doing anything. If you are in the UK consult the Citizen's Advice Bureau.

If you still believe this is worth pursuing, then you need to talk to your boss or to HR. It's reasonable to ask your boss the same question you asked your colleagues - has anyone been spreading rumours about you? You might show your boss the WhatsApp conversation with Anne, but be aware that if you wrote anything offensive, hostile, or accusatory in this conversation there could be repercussions for you. If you don't feel comfortable with your boss go to HR. Be aware that unless it can ber established somehow that Anne made false accusations about you then it is unlikely that anything will come of this.

If the situation were different and you did know what Anne was saying about you, and it was serious, then I would start by going to HR. Going to your boss who is her friend won't help. Tell them what Anne has been saying about you - take notes on what she has said, and tell them exactly. Show them the chats where she admits to lying. Specifically say that this makes for a "hostile work environment" and that she is "bullying". Tell them that your boss is Anne's friend and that makes you reluctant to go to her. *Don't* tell them, or anyone, that you refuse to work with Anne yet. It makes you look like you are inventing problems to get out of working with her. If HR takes action, great. If they don't, and the accusations Anne makes are serious, then consult a lawyer.

There are two reasons for doing this - one is that HR might make the behaviour stop. The second is that you've established that you complained about her behaviour, which might be useful if this ever comes to law.

To answer your legal question, I am not a lawyer but in general your company can make you work with anyone they like, unless you can establish that her behaviour is so bad that working with her is unreasonable. If you otherwise refused to work with her then they might fire you.

My advice is to  work with Anne as directed, while looking for another job. The description of the rest of your colleagues doesn't make this sound like a great place to work. If you're going to go another route consult a lawyer (or the other people I mentioned above) before doing anything drastic.

Comment: How are you still employed if it is serious @questioner? Did she not tell your boss?

Comment: If you don't know what was said then why do you think it was bad? Why do you think it was anything? Have you asked somebody? Without knowing what you are accused of it's hard to make a complaint. What did you say in your WhatsApp conversation?

Comment: If you don't know what was said, how do you know your boss believes it?